# Encoding $_GET[] values with PHP to make them broswer safe

Tags: php, browser, encoding

With PHP, which function is best to be used with $_GET[] values to make them browser safe?

I have read up on a few htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities(). Should one of those be used or is there another function that would work better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) suffices to encode the HTML special characters. [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) is only necessary if you want to use characters that can not be encoded with the character encoding you are using.

But make sure to specify the *quote_style* parameter when you want to use the output in an attribute value quoted with single quotes like:

```
echo "<input type='text' value='".htmlspecialchars($_GET['foobar'], ENT_QUOTES)."'>";
```

And to specify the *charset* parameter when you’re using a character encoding other than ISO 8859-1:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['foobar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `htmlspecialchars()` to display `$_GET` variables, and use `urlencode()` to encode them.

Answer (score 1):

htmlspecialchars() should be applied to every $_GET variable you output into your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this just for safety (removing <script>'s etc) rather than because you need to make sure characters are encoded correctly (although that could definitely be a concern) it could be worth looking at [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), which will  remove tags entirely, rather than just encoding the < and > symbols. This is a bit nicer in some cases - <b>hello</b> will become just "hello", rather than having the tags converted to become visible.